# Using Javascript reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable method on Birt handlers

Tags: javascript, eclipse, birt

I trying to use reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable to define global variable on the OnFetch Javascript method of the data set like that:

```js
flag = 1;
if(row.Percent>10)
reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("flag", flag);
```

and to retrieve the variable on the beforeRender method like that:

```js
var flg = reportContext.getPersistentGlobalVariable("flag");
if(flg==1)
reportContext.getDesignHandle().findElement("chartToHide").drop();
```

but by running the report receiving this error:

> org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: There are errors evaluating script "reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("flag", true);":
>       Fail to execute script in function __bm_onFetch().

Answer (score 1):

In theory this code should work because the method [setPersistentGlobalVariable](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.birt.runtime/org.eclipse.birt.runtime/4.3.0/org/eclipse/birt/report/engine/api/script/IReportContext.java#IReportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.io.Serializable%29) expects a serializable object:

```
void setPersistentGlobalVariable( String name, Serializable obj );
```

but in practice in Rhino scripts it seems it can only handle a String, try this:

```
var flag = "1";
if(row.Percent>10)
reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("flag", flag);


var flg = reportContext.getPersistentGlobalVariable("flag");
if(flg=="1")
reportContext.getDesignHandle().findElement("chartToHide").drop();
```

Comment: thanks , your answer was helpful , but despite I fixed the code as your'e suggestion it's still not working. pls see the new question I asked about it : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959510/using-javascriprt-reportcontext-setpersistentglobalvariable-method-on-birt-handl